# Wrong Domain When Resetting Password

Tags: login, password, forgot-password

I moved my EE install from the test server to the live server but when I’m trying to reset the password at site.com/system/index.php the email I get has the domain for the old server under:

> To reset your password, please go to the following page:
>   http://olddomain.com/admin.php?D=cp&C=login&M=reset_password&id=0n6xTd0m

How do I fix this so it points to the new domain? I already replaced all instances of the old domain in the database file, so not sure where this would be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you updated your config file?

```
$config['base_url']   = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

In the URL and path settings page check the setting 'Control panel directory URL' as that controls the URL in the password reset email.